# Hibernate sessions fetch stale data when using async controllers and long polling

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, grails, asynchronous

I have a problem with async controllers in Grails. Consider the following controller:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
class RentController  {
    def myService


    UserProperties props
    def beforeInterceptor = {
        this.props = fetchUserProps() 
    }


    //..other actions

    @Transactional
    def rent(Long id) {
        //check some preconditions here, calling various service methods...
        if (!allOk) {
            render status: 403, text: 'appropriate.message.key'
            return
        }

        //now we long poll because most of the time the result will be
        //success within a couple of seconds
        AsyncContext ctx = startAsync()
        ctx.timeout = 5 * 1000 * 60 + 5000
        ctx.start {
            try {
                //wait for external service to confirm - can take a long time or even time out
                //save appropriate domain objects if successful
                //placeRental is also marked with @Transactional (if that makes any difference)
                def result = myService.placeRental() 
                if (result.success) {
                    render text:"OK", status: 200
                } else {
                    render status:400, text: "rejection.reason.${result.rejectionCode}"
                }
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                log.error "Rental process failed", t
                render text: "Rental process failed with exception ${t?.message}", status: 500
            } finally {
                ctx.complete()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The controller and service code appear to work fine (though the above code is simplified) but will sometimes cause a database session to get 'stuck in the past'.

Let's say I have a `UserProperties` instance whose property `accountId` is updated from `1` to `20` somewhere else in the application while a `rent` action is waiting in the async block. As the async block eventually terminates one way or another (it may succeed, fail or time out), the app will sometimes get a stale `UserProperties` instance with `accountId: 1`. Let's say I refresh the updated user's properties page, I will see `accountId: 1` about 1 time per 10 refreshes while the rest of the time it will be `20` - and this is on my development machine where noone else is accessing the application (though the same behaviour can be observed in production). My connection pool also holds 10 connections so I suspect there may be a correlation here.

Other strange things will happen - for example, I will get `StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)` from actions doing something as simple as `render (UserProperties.list() as JSON)` - after the response had already rendered (successfuly apart from the noise in the logs) and despite the action being annotated with `@Transactional(readOnly=true)`.

A stale session doesn't seem to appear every time and so far our solution was to restart the server every evening (the app has few users for now), but the error is annoying and the cause was hard to pinpoint. My guess is that a DB transaction doesn't get committed or rolled back because of the async code, but GORM, Spring and Hibernate have many nooks and crannies where things could get stuck.

We're using Postgres 9.4.1 (9.2 on a dev machine, same problem), Grails 2.5.0, Hibernate plugin 4.3.8.1, Tomcat 8, Cache plugin 1.1.8, Hibernate Filter plugin 0.3.2 and the Audit Logging plugin 1.0.1 (other stuff too, obviously, but this feels like it could be relevant). My datasource config contains:

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory'
    singleSession = true
    flush.mode = 'manual'
    format_sql = true
}
```

Comment: why do you use @Transactional at the controller level?

Comment: Because most of the other actions are read-only and I've seen this pattern in auto-generated Grails controllers: letting Hibernate know an action is read only lets it skip some steps that would otherwise be required. You also get an exception trying to write anything which is a nice feedback, letting you know your assumptions are wrong. `@Transactional` on an action overrides the read-only setting for that action.

Comment: I've gone and removed `@Transactional` from the controller (and from the problematic action, the service methods are annotated, anyway), no improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Grails bug.](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9198) And a nasty one, everything seems OK until your app starts acting funny in completely unrelated parts of the app.